# Using Box to optimise memory allocation of optional, known length arrays

Tags: rust, serde

I have a question about memory allocation strategies in a specific situation.

I have a large number of structs that are coming from a JSON API via serde. There is a specific field in the JSON response which will, for a small minority of cases, exist and contain an array of exactly 11 elements. In the majority of cases this field will not exist at all in the response. All responses need to be stored.

The majority of responses will be of the format:

```
{
  id: 1,
  event: "None"
}
```

A minority of responses will be of the format:

```
{
  id: 2,
  event: "something",
  event_details : [11 json objects here]
}
```

If I define my struct for parsing the JSON as:

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Event {
  id: u32,
  event: String,
  // EventDetail is a struct with an u32 and string field
  events: Option<[EventDetail; 11]>
 }
```

I can see using [deepsizeof](https://docs.rs/deepsize/latest/deepsize/trait.DeepSizeOf.html) crate that my `Vec<Event>` that gets created takes up ~500MB of memory. If I change the `events` field to be `events: Option<Box<[EventDetail; 11]>>` the memory usage drops to ~150MB.

My understanding here is that since Box is allocated at runtime instead of compile time, when a JSON response comes in that is lacking the `events` field, then the 11 item array does not need to be allocated. Am I correct here? And is this a valid use case for Box or is there a better way to do this?

I also tried `events: Option<Vec<EventDetail>>`, which resulted in slightly higher memory assignment than Box. I assume this is down to padding.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, this is all correct. `Option<[T; N]>` always allocates space for the array, even if it's not used, whereas `Option<Box<...>>` allocates enough space for the box pointer, but *not* the thing it points to unless needed. Hiding the large data behind a `Box` indirection is 100% the correct call here.

`Vec` is a pointer (basically a `Box`) plus the size of the vector and its capacity, so `Option<Vec<...>>` will usually be three times the overhead, as it will allocate space for *all of* the pointer, the size and the capacity, of the (potentially nonexistent) vector. But at that point, we're arguing in units of bytes, so it's silly to debate size differences at that scale.

(`Vec` also stores the memory allocator, but the default allocator `Global` is a zero-sized type)

Since you know the size in advance, I'd go with `Option<Box<[EventDetail; 11]>>` rather than the vector, since the vector is just pointlessly pushing data to runtime that could be known at compile-time.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I missed it but I don't see this use case listed in any of the common rust guides/docs on Box use cases, to me this use case would be more common than things like Recursive structs

Comment: FWIW you could also just use `Vec` with no `Option` layer. This should have basically the same overhead as an `Option<Box>` (plus length+capacity, though) and you could use `#[serde(default)]` to deserialize a missing value as an empty `Vec` (assuming that a present but empty array is not a distinct state that needs to be distinguishable).

Comment: Since the array is fixed size I would assume an empty array is not currently an option.

Answer (score 1):

Just a partial answer for the "or is there a better way to do this?" part.

Depending on the context of usage of the `struct Event`, another option is to store the `event_details` arrays *externally* to the `struct`. Depending on your performance constraints and how you resolve identity for `Event`s, you could store them in another `Vec` or a dictionary (`HashMap`?), indexing by `Event.id`.